# Redis databases on a dev machine with multiple projects

Tags: redis

How do you manage multiple projects on your development and/or testing machine, when some of those projects use Redis databases?

There are 2 major problems:

1. Redis doesn't have named databases (only numbers 0-16)
2. Tests are likely to execute FLUSHDB on each run

Right now, I think we have three options:

1. Assign different databases for each project, each dev and test environment
2. Prefix keys with a project name using something like `redis-namespace`
3. Nuke and seed the databases anytime you switch between projects

The first one is problematic if multiple projects assign "0" for the main use and "1" for the test and such. Even if Project B decided to change to "2" and "3", another member in the project might have a conflict in another projects for him. In other words, that approach is not SCM friendly.

For the second one, it's a bad idea simply because it adds needless overhead on runtime performance and memory efficiency. And no matter what you do, another project might be already using the same key coincidentally when you joined the project.

The third option is rather a product of compromise, but sometimes I want to keep my local data untouched while I deploy small patches for another projects.

I know this could be a feature request for Redis, but I need a solution now.

Any ideas, practices?

Answer (score 16):

If the projects are independent and so do not need to share data, it is much better to use multiple redis instances - each project configuration has a port number rather than a database name/id. Create an appropriately named config file and startup script for each one so that you can get whichever instance you need running with a single click.

Make sure you update the save settings in each config file as well as setting the ports - Multiple instances using the same dump.rdb file will work, but lead to some rather confusing bugs.

I also use separate instances for development and testing so that the test instance never writes anything to disk and can be flushed at the start of each test.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is moving away from multiple databases, so I would recommend you start migrating put of that mechanism sooner rather than later. This means one instance per db. Given the very low overhead of running Redis, this isn't a problem from a resources standpoint.

That said, you can specify the number of databases, and providing A naming standard would work. For example, configure redis to have say, 60 DBS and you add 10 for the test db. For example db3 uses db13 for testing.

It sounds like your dev, test, and prod environments are pretty tied together. If so, I'd suggest moving away from that. Using separate instances is the easiest route to that, and provides protection against cross purpose contamination. Between this and the future of redis being single-db per instance, separate instances is the best route.

Comment: I disagree that multiple instances being low overhead. Port number is one of the most limited resources on a development machine, and availability depends on environment, thus can't be fixed and put in git for other people in the team. It means that even designers must understand how environment variable works.

Comment: for instance, I have library like https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex and there, it uses db15 for testing so that it won't accidentally step on contributor's real data.

Comment: Sure there is technically a finite number of available ports. But do you really think you are going to have about 64,000 instances on a single dev system? Pragmatically speaking if each instance used 1Mb of memory that would need to be on a system with 64Gb of RAM. I would also be concerned about developers not understanding environment variables. Your example project on github would trash several of my databases. You simply can not assume a given database number is "yours", and that developers will not be using the one you choose.

Comment: And just in case you do expect to actually hit a port limit, remember that only applies to each IP address the system uses. You could use multiple IP addresses combined with multiple ports. The reality is that available ports would run out well after CPU, memory, and I/O. That said, I would recommend revisiting some of your fundamental assumptions. Developers are expected to know the name of a redis server, but can not be expected to understand en environment variable or port number? I'd bet your developers are smarter than that.

Comment: I'm talking in context of cognitive overhead, not in physical availability. What port number to choose other than 6379? Anything beyond that is too arbitrary and requires knowledge on what stack uses what number, etc. In comparison, look at config/database.yml, hardcoding "my_project_development" in git has been proven to be much less conflicting and easy for anyone.

Comment: So what prevents you from making port number part if the config file? You could even have a standard redis runnin on the standard redis port using a static name that stores the mapping and dynamically retrieve the server/port pair. Library connects to the config redis, gets then values for "myproject:development" and the connects automatically. Then all you need is the name. Of course, this is doable in a config file too. Cognitively, port number is the same as database number. You replace one number with another. Sure the number of digits changes but that isn't really an issue. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12272/discussion-between-kenn-and-the-real-bill)

Comment: Sure, gimme about 10 minutes to wrap something up.