# Errors when try to run redis server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I tried to run the command `redis server` and I get these error messages:

```
30260:C 06 Mar 19:19:52.861 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
30260:M 06 Mar 19:19:52.862 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
30260:M 06 Mar 19:19:52.862 # Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
30260:M 06 Mar 19:19:52.862 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
30260:M 06 Mar 19:19:52.862 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

I already created a user for redis before because I used it in another Rails application and now I'm creating a new project that will also use this tool.

So, when I run `ps aux | grep redis`

```
fillype   5274  0.0  0.0  14244  1024 pts/2    S+   19:36   0:00 grep --color redis
redis    29157  0.0  0.1  40292 11120 ?        Ssl  19:16   0:01 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I know that this question is the same as [redis-server in ubuntu14.04: Bind address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947076/redis-server-in-ubuntu14-04-bind-address-already-in-use/38661188) but their solutions doesn't work to me, that is, to kill the process.

Comment: Your redis server is already running. So it should be fine for you app. But, do you want to access the same redis instance for different apps ? You should think of a Docker environment ;)

Comment: If you need multiple instances, checkout https://jeremysmith.co/posts/2013-01-25-setting-up-multiple-instances-of-redis-on-a-mac/ . He also posted some links to stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148390/redis-databases-on-a-dev-machine-with-multiple-projects and http://chrislaskey.com/blog/342/running-multiple-redis-instances-on-the-same-server/

Comment: thank you! I'll check it out